# Why does my background keep static black?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift development and for good practice I wanted to try and make the background color for the view change all random. The issue is that the color changes but only to black even if the values prints all random RGB. This is my code, can someone explain why this happens? Thank you...

```
 @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {
    let redRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0...255)
    let greenRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0...255)
    let blueRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0...255)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: redRGB, green: greenRGB, blue: blueRGB, alpha: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. [`UIColor.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init) values go from `0.0` to `1.0`, not from `0.0` to `255.0`.
2. Your alpha needs to be `1` for opaque.  `0` is fully transparent.

   ```
   let redRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
   let greenRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
   let blueRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
   self.view.backgroundColor =
       UIColor(red: redRGB, green: greenRGB, blue: blueRGB, alpha: 1)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why is it from 0 to 1 though?

Comment: That's just the way they designed it.  It does confuse a lot of people.

Comment: If the best you can do for red, green or blue is 256 colors, it makes sense to have a value between 0 and 255. But more and more color systems use more than 256 possibilities for a color component. In that case it makes more sense to define a value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've been going through your code and found you are sending alpha: 0.
that's why you are viewing the Windows background colour which is black.

following is the correct code.

```
 @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {
    let redRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
    let greenRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
    let blueRGB = CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: redRGB, green: greenRGB, blue: blueRGB, alpha: 1)
}
```